# how to display JSON data in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a json file which contains data like this

```
{"name": "Mohamed"}
```

and in my js file I need to read the value in an array like this

```
[{value: "name"}]
```

how can I do this ?

Comment: parse json and wrap with array: ```[JSON.parse(data)]```

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.parse(data)`

Such as

```
const ok = '{"name": "Mohamed"}';
const ok2 = JSON.parse(ok);
console.log(ok2.name);
```

Output will be `Mohamed`

Answer (score 0):

The data you have is JSON.stringify() data.

For example:

You have an object

```
var a = { name: 'Harsimar', admin: false }
```

To send that data to the server in a body, you converts the data into a string with this method called

```
var b = JSON.stringify(a);
```

Now you have to data in this format (The object has become a string, now you cannot access the keys or data of the object directly)

```
b = "{"name":"Harsimar","admin":false}"
```

This is a one way to see, now the question you have asked is how we can use the string data as object. We need to reverse the proccess.

```
var c = JSON.parse(b)
```

So here, JSON.parse() is a method which we can use from converting the data from string -> object again.
Now the variable c is equal variable a.

To put that object into an array, you can simply put it [c] and it will give output as you intend.
[{ name: 'Harsimar', admin: false }]